# What's the technique of using phrases of different meanings separated by a conjunction called?

Tags: grammar

I've been wondering this for a while. Here's some examples:
*taking lives and orders*, *made cookies but no conversation*. I googled *phrases of different types in one clause*, but this didn't yield any useful results. This doesn't seem like parallelism, since the phrases have different meanings in context of the sentence. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are two very similar. If you search for **zeugma,**  (Wiki, Google, but especially the search tab on this site top/left margin) it should lead to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeugma is one of stylistic syntactic figures. It is defined as 'the use of a single word in relation to two other parts of a sentence althoughgrammatically or logically the word applies to only one of them' /Macmillan Dictionary/. For example, the joke 'The cinema-makers should shoot fewer films and more actors' is another example of zeugma.